# Is it possible to get values of custom fields when fetching a bug using Bugzilla RPC?

Tags: xml-rpc, bugzilla

If I add custom fields to my bugs in Bugzilla 4+, is it possible to get the values of tehse when fetching the bug using Bugzilla RPC (I use the XML one)? Before I think this was stored in the `internals` part of the reply, but now I can't seem to find it. I tried including them by adding them to the `include_fields` in my request, but doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how I could have missed it before, I even searched the entire page on "custom". Perhaps the text has been updated afterwards. But it now states that all custom fields will be returned when using `get` on a bug.

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.0/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#get